# Jquery next() not working in list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am creating an audio player, playing one song after the other. Songs are displayed as a list of `<li>` elements. Once a song is finished, it should load the next one on the list. If there's no next one, it goes back to the first one.

```
    <ul>                                                                                            
        <li class="song playing">
            <a data-src="http://.../song1.wav" data-title="Title 1">
                <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Title 1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="song">
            <a data-src="http://.../song2.wav" data-title="Title 2">
                <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Title 2
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="song">
            <a data-src="http://.../song3.wav" data-title="Title 3">
                <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Title 3
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And the Javascript

```
    trackEnded: function() {
                // The problem :
            var next = $('li.playing').next();
                // This ends up always be true:
            if ( !next.length ){ next = $('.song').first(); }

                // (Less relevant to the problem)
            next.addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
            $('.fa').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
            $('.fa', next).removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');
            audio.load($('a', next).attr('data-src'));
            $('.title span').text($('a', next).attr('data-title'));
            audio.play();
        },
```

The `next()` element always returns empty, even though they are more children elements in the same `ul` element.

Am I using `next()` wrong?

EDIT: `next()` was fine, another function was removing the class `playing` right before, making the selector return nothing. I should have checked that first.

Comment: A simple example seems to work for me.

Comment: Seems okay. https://jsfiddle.net/foybxges/

Comment: Thanks! I'm now really confused, my code returns an empty object but your JSfiddle works perfectly.

Comment: Please update your post with a runnable example (snippet) that reproduces your issue here.